# Convert the Time from time zone -500 to the device located time zone

Tags: android

I have the datetime in the format like

```
2016-12-26 02:54:20 -0500
```

Now I need to convert this time to the device located time format.
If the device used in the Singapore then the time should convert automatically to the Singapore time zone, if device is in India then automatically it should convert to Indian time zone.
Please help to get the solution, Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, is this in sql time format?

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, I am using java.util.Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method

```
public String convertTimeZone(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    inFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Date toConvert = inFormat.parse(date);
    date = inFormat.format(toConvert);
    return date.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shubham this code is working Just awesome.